# Scripting VM checkpoint in SCVMM via Powershell

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, checkpoint

Thought this would be a no brainer, but I couldn't find this question in here.

Having trouble getting a simple powershell script to work for creating a checkpoint. It appears to complete successfully but I'm not seeing a checkpoint in SCVMM so I'm wondering if I'm missing something here.

```
Import-Module -Name "virtualmachinemanager"
Get-VMMServer SCVMMSERVER01.CORP.COM
Checkpoint-VM -Name Create-Checkpoint -AsJob -ComputerName COMPUTER001 -SnapshotName "Deployment-$((Get-Date).toshortdatestring())"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use SCVMM cmdlet [`New-SCVMCheckpoint`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801715.aspx)?

```
Get-SCVirtualMachine -Name 'VM01' | New-SCVMCheckpoint
```

or

```
New-SCVMCheckpoint -VM 'VM01'
```

When I tried to use the Hyper-V cmdlet on an SCVMM VM I got an error

> Cannot convert value of type SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.VM to HyperV.PowerShell.VirtualMachine.

Comment: This got me in the right direction. The following worked for me  
  
  
`New-SCVMCheckpoint -VM Computer001 -Name "Deployment-$((Get-Date).toshortdatestring())" -VMMServer SCVMMServer001`